# row_number() over partition in hql

Tags: hql, window-functions

What is the equivalent of row_number() over partition in hql
I have the following query in hql:

```sql
select s.Companyname, p.Productname, sum(od.Unitprice * od.Quantity - od.Discount) as SalesAmount FROM OrderDetails as od inner join od.Orders as o inner join od.Products as p " +
                                                              "inner join p.Suppliers as s" +
                                                      " where o.Orderdate between '2010/01/01' and '2014/01/01' GROUP BY s.Companyname,p.Productname"
```

I want to do partition by `s.Companyname` where `RowNumber <= n`.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know you cannot use `row_number()` neither in [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) nor in [JPQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language). I propose to use a [native SQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) query in this case:

```java
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;
...

    String sQuery = "SELECT q.* FROM (" +
            "SELECT s.company_name, " +
               "p.product_name, " +
               "sum(od.unit_price * od.quantity - od.discount) as SalesAmount, " +
               "row_number() OVER (partition by s.company_name) as rn " +
            "FROM OrderDetails od " +
            "INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.id = od.order_id " +
            "INNER JOIN Products p ON p.id = od.product_id " +
            "INNER JOIN Suppliers s ON s.id = p.supplier_id " +
            "WHERE o.order_date between '2010/01/01' and '2014/01/01') as q " +
        "WHERE rn <= :n";

    List<ResultDbo> results = new ArrayList<>();
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sQuery);
    query.setParameter("n", n);
    List<Object[]> resultSet = query.getResultList();
    for (Object[] resultItem : resultSet) {
        ResultDbo result = new ResultDbo();
        result.setCompanyName((String) resultItem[0]);
        result.setProductName((String) resultItem[1]);
        result.setSalesAmount((String) resultItem[2]);
        results.add(result);
    }
```

If you ever try to use `OVER()` in HQL you'll almost certainly get some validation exception like `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: OVER near line 1, column 42 ...`

Answer (score 1):

Row number by partition looks like this:

```sql
row_number() over (partition by s.Companyname)
```

You can not use window function `row_number` in `where` clause, so you have to do subquery with filter by its value:

```sql
select * from (
  -- here is your query
  select 
    ...,
    row_number() over (partition by s.Companyname) as rowNum
  from ...
  where ...
) as res
where rowNum <= n
```