# How to write MAX and OVER (PARTITION BY) functions in JPA query

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, window-functions

I need to get one column(revision) maximum value based on another column(drawingNumber). Can anyone tell me the JPA query for this functionality.

I have written the following query and this query is not working.

Please help me how to write MAX and OVER (PARTITION BY) functions in JPA query.

```
    @Query("select dr FROM
        (SELECT MAX(dr.revision) over (PARTITION BY d.drawing_number) AS latest_revision
        FROM DrawingRate dr
        JOIN dr.drawing d
        JOIN d.modifiedBy mb
        WHERE mb.Id=:Id
        OR piu.Id=:Id
        ORDER BY d.localModifiedOn DESC NULLS LAST
        ) WHERE dr.revision = :latest_revision")
```

This Spring data JPA query is not working while running this showing the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:  unexpected
>   token: ( near line 1, column 16 [select dr from (select
>   max(dr.revision) over (partition by d.drawing_number)  AS
>   last_enrolment_date from entity.DrawingRate dr join dr.drawing d JOIN
>   d.modifiedBy mb left join dr.modifiedBy u  WHERE mb.Id=:IdOR
>   piu.Id=:Id order by d.localModifiedOn DESC NULLS LAST) WHERE
>   dr.revision  = :latest_revision]

Please help me how to write MAX and OVER (PARTION BY) functions in JPA query.

Comment: HQL doesn't support modern SQL features. You need to use a native query.

Comment: I need to get one column(revision) maximum value based on another column(drawingNumber). Can you tell me the JPA query for this functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [row\_number() over partition in hql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778039/row-number-over-partition-in-hql)