# JPQL select with group by, having and max

Tags: spring-boot, h2, jpql

I need to select 4 users for each country which have max points **with JPQL**

my User entity has columns:
id, String country and Long points

I tried to do smth like this

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.points IN (SELECT u2.points FROM User u2 GROUP BY u2.country, u2.points HAVING COUNT(u2.points) <= 4)
```

can somebody help me?

Comment: you are using h2 as your database ?

Comment: "Rank() over partition by" is what might help your use-case, but for that you will need to use a native query, as JPQL does not support this. A Reference implementation can be seen here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55242187/how-to-write-max-and-over-partition-by-functions-in-jpa-query